# How to delete some records or files after X time - Laravel 5

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a script, to delete some records after X time, I will choose it, but I don't know, How can I do that? 
And the same thing with my files, I want to delete some files after X time from upload for example, and to do that, I will delete the file from my storage, and the file record from the database, **but that will make my site slow**, Any way to do that without problems

Use this for example?

[Soft Deleting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#soft-deleting) or [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling)

My Table is: 
[image: My Table Image]
so I want to delete this record for example after 2 hours from creation? but I have a lot of records? how to do that?

Files Table :
[image: Files Table Part 1]
[image: Files Table Part 2]
these are my records, they contain the path of my files, but every file will expire after 5 days from creation for example, so I will delete it from the path and delete there record from the database after that. but that will make the site very slow? any way to do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel handles this quite well.  You were correct, use the [Task Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling)

What I would recommend would be to set up two different jobs, because you have two different criteria (2 hours, 5 days) for the time between tasks.

For the records, you can set up a check within your job to see when the record was created, and delete those that are more than 2 hours old.  Something like:

```
$schedule->call(function () {
        DB::table('your_table')->whereRaw('created_at >= now() - interval 2 hour')
    })->daily();
```

If you use Carbon, you can change the query around using something like:

```
->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(120)->toDateTimeString());
```

Same thing with the file deletion - make a job that deletes those files older than 5 days.  It won't slow your system much if you set the job to go off maybe once a day at your least popular times.  So, when making your job:

```
$schedule->job(new YourJob)->dailyAt('3:00');
```

There are a lot of ways to do this.  But, you'll need to learn how the scheduler works (easy) and then you can employ the possible solutions here.

Comment: can I use events?

Comment: Sure.  But, you don't need to with the scheduler as per the above.  I think simplest to just use the scheduler - unless you have a need for more precision.  This answer (if you schedule the record deletion to fire every hour and the file deletion to fire once a day) will get you to where you want I think.  If you worry about slowing your site - events might not be the best choice, depending on how you implement.

Comment: But, when using the Task Scheduler, do I need to run `artisan schedule:run` & `queue:work` each time? To work?

Comment: Just set it once via cron job.  Check out the docs on schedule here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling  This will walk you through what you need to know - then use the hints in the answer above and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks but I mean, After running `php artisan schedule:run` ? Will Laravel do the rest? I do not need to run it again?

Comment: Anyway to run this Cron Job without SSH or entering the cPanel?  `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Not that I know of, you need server access to start cron.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 3):

```
Files::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subHours(2))->delete();
```

Make sure you have the Carbon package installed